# How to focus on specific non-form element in safari?

Tags: javascript, safari

Is it possible to use javascript to focus anywhere but the URL if the focus is on the single form element on the page and the use presses <kbd>Tab</kbd>? There's a setting "press tab to highlight each item on a webpage", which does allow to do exactly that by default, but is there a way to force such behavior without that setting?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the `tabindex` property on any element to make it focusable.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.tabIndex

http://snook.ca/archives/accessibility_and_usability/elements_focusable_with_tabindex

Comment: Safari ignores this attribute

Comment: Thanks @Fluffy  I didn't realize that.  I wonder if you could attach a `onkeyup` event handler to the window to catch the tab key and tell it what to focus next.  I won't post this as an answer because I don't really have a way to test it.